# setHidden: has unwanted delay

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit, grand-central-dispatch

I currently have a really weird bug.

A method gets called, that is supposed to hide an `UIActivityIndicatorView` by stopping it (automatic hiding when stopped is enabled) and an `UIImageView` called `badIndicator`.

As a replacement it is supposed to show another `UIImageView` called `goodIndicator`.

```
[goodIndicator setHidden:NO];
[badIndicator setHidden:YES];
[refreshIndicator stopAnimating];
NSLog(@"statussetting good should be completed");
```

The console prints the following right away, but it takes about three seconds for the changes to happen on the screen.

```
2013-05-31 20:24:57.835 app name[5948:1603] statussetting good should be completed
```

I have tried calling the `setNeedsDisplay` method on the objects and on the parent view and also replace hidden with alpha.
Still get the same problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you are calling this from a background thread.  All interaction with `UIKit` needs to happen from the main thread.  Try using:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [goodIndicator setHidden:NO];
    [badIndicator setHidden:YES];
    [refreshIndicator stopAnimating];
    NSLog(@"statussetting good should be completed");
});
```

Comment: Perfect, it works like a charm. It's being called from a completion handler of an URL-Request.

I was not aware, that this runs on a different thread

Answer (score 2):

you need to call this method in main thread.Try using:

```
-(void)hideControls { 
    [goodIndicator setHidden:NO]; 
    [badIndicator setHidden:YES]; 
    [refreshIndicator stopAnimating]; 
    NSLog(@"statussetting good should be completed"); 
}
```

Comment: Your example is essentially the same thing that the poster has supplied.  The only thing different is that you mention to call it on the main thread, but didn't elaborate.  In order to be helpful, I suggest providing an example as to HOW to ensure that the code is run on the main thread, not unlike the answer above.